# Can I run a brushless motor on Raspberry Pi via Python?

Tags: motor, raspberry-pi, brushless-dc-motor

I am using a [1000kv brushless motor](https://www.flyrobo.in/a2212_1000kv_brushless_motor_for_rc_airplane) and [30A ESC](https://www.flyrobo.in/simonk_30a_2-3s_brushless_esc_for_rc) and I want to run it. Does anyone have any idea for that?

Comment: (1) 1000KV = Number of revolutions done by motor per volt of supply (1000 revolutions per volt here. If supply voltage is 10 volts then motor will rotate at 10000RPM).

Comment: (2) It depends on your battery. (3) Python is OK, because interface with only three or four control signals, without any external motor controller, is simple.

Comment: @tilfong were I the only one which read 100 kilovolt at the first glance?:D

Comment: It's not clear how that ESC is driven but most probably you could drive it with any MCU under the sky

Comment: @Lorenzo Marcantonio, ESC and BLDC are complicated and expensive toys, easy to use, and also easy to fry. I fried more those toys I could afford, before I gave up and switched back to cheapy DC motors. :) 
***(ESC) Electronic Speed Control***- Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_speed_control

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the ESC expects a PWM input like a servo. So you can use a Raspberry Pi timer to generate that signal and modern ESCs accept 3.3V signals directly. You’ll have to set the PWM frequency to something like 50Hz and generate 1-2ms pulses for “throttle”.

Compatibility between motor and ESC is not addressed in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

The ESC is intended for PWM control.  You  can use the [pigpio library](https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/) for Python to control it.  Set the PWM frequency to 50Hz, then set the duty cycle to control the speed.

The ESC you linked to should be capable of driving the motor you linked to, though you will most likely have to configure it for the correct current or voltage limits (the linked page refers to configuring the throttle range, which boils down to setting minimum and maximum values for the current.)